# Any Yii Validation Pattern on - How to allow insert with required fields missing?

Tags: yii

This may seem weird at a first sight.

We wish to allow the user to SAVE INTO DATABASE, even if, some required fields are missing.

Then, when the user wishes to PUBLISH those records, it should NOT be allowed, because those required fields are missing.

Perhaps, create some sort of required variation that tell us:
Required for PUBLISHING but not for INSERTING;

Taking into consideration your Yii knowledge, is there some sort of pattern we should use on this case?

### UPDATE

Scenarios seems to be a nice approach, but the documentation suggests adding:

```
$model = new MyActiveRecord('Inserting');
```

On our controller.

On my controller, I have, however, this:

```
public function actionCreate()
{
  $this->layout = 'admin';

  $model=new HsGuestbook;

  $localized[] = $this->getExtraModelGuestTr();

  if(isset($_POST['HsGuestbook']))
  {
   ...
```

So, I've tried to do:

```
  if(isset($_POST['HsGuestbook']))
  {
     //check validation scenarios
     if ($model->status === 0) { //if publish isn't set:
          $model->setScenario('Insert'); 
     } elseif ($model->status === 1){
           $model->setScenario('Publish'); 
     }
```

And on my model:

```
public function rules()
{
    return array(
         array('name, category', 'required', 'on'=>'Insert'),
         array('name, category, image', 'required', 'on'=>'Publish'))
```

I got no validations displayed.

Comment: Please take a look at [CModel::rules](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CModel/#rules-detail) and [CModel::scenario](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CModel#scenario-detail) first. They may be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The edit is a total different question so I'm creating a new response

Before assigning the scenario, you need to fill your model with the post values

```
   <?php if(isset($_POST['HsGuestbook'])) {
         //Assign the post value to your model
         $model->attributes =  $_POST['HsGuestbook'];          
         //check validation scenarios 
          if ($model->status === 0) 
          { 
            //if publish isn't set: 
            $model->setScenario('Insert');
           } 
          elseif ($model->status === 1)
          { 
            $model->setScenario('Publish');
              }
         //Here you should validate/save the datas
        } ?>
```

And then you can validate the datas with

```
$model->validate();
```

Wich return true or false.
Or you can validate the datas while saving them:

```
$model->save(); // will validate the datas then save them
```

It also return true or false

Answer (score 3):

You could use Yii's scenarios:
You declare one scenario like "Inserting" and an onther like "Publishing".

In your model's rules you'll have:

```
array('username, password, all your required attibutes', 'required', 'on'=>'Publishing'), 
// You defined with the "on" the scenario(s) in which the rule must apply
```

And then in your controller you'll call:

If you need to insert you set the scenario to "Inserting"

```
$model = new MyActiveRecord('Inserting');
```

If you need to publish you set the scenario to "Publishing"

```
$model = new MyActiveRecord('Publishing');
```

Link: [Understanding Scenarios](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/266/understanding-scenarios/)

Comment: That seems to be a nice approach. I will look further on the next hours. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Keep in mind that the restriction for not allowing required fields comes from the Database not yii. Your model is based upon the schema in place in the database. Even if you change the rule in your model class to safe the database will not allow the insert to go through as the required field is missing.

I would not recommend removing any restrictions from the database, how about adding another field to your table which marks the entry as publishable or unpublishable. You can overcome the missing required entries by specifying default values and setting the publish flag to false.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your valuable comment.